# How to install custom Python libraries from within spark-submit Python code

Tags: python, apache-spark

I want to be able to run a command such as `spark-submit test_file.py --dependencies= adobe_analytics` which does below tasks

1. Installs the libraries that are passed in `dependencies` parameter
2. Makes those libraries available from within the Spark session that is run with the `spark-submit` command

My `test_file.py` looks like below -

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
# import all libraries here 
from adobe_analytics import Client
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("yarn").appName("myapp").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
#.... more logic
```

I have this code running on Google Dataproc cluster. Here is the link for the custom library that I need to install -

https://github.com/SaturnFromTitan/adobe_analytics

What is the best way to approach this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but I had a similar issue on a project that I've worked on, and our workaround to it was to zip our custom library and pass it through parameter on spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit --py-files libs/customlib.zip file.py
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is there no other way to do this ?

Comment: you can install on the cluster itself, but keep in mind that you have to install on master and slaves nodes. Me and my team did not have access to install resources on the cluster direclty so we had to pass it thru --py-files